# How to disable exponential format?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

My application is generating some Excel sheets from values fetched from a database. Some of the Excel cells with numeric values (more than 6-7 digits) are displayed in exponential form like `5.45465E+22`. I tried formatting those cells as Number, and as Text, but still I get values in exponential form.

How, please, can we disable such format for those cells in Excel?

Comment: Can you export all the information from the database to a txt file instead? Importing the txt into Excel afterwards shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2007 upwards, you can choose the 'Number' format (available on the Home tab), but remember to widen the column to take the new number format.

One more thing to add; you can apply the 'Number' format to the whole worksheet by selecting the button to the left of column 'A' and up from row '1' then choosing the 'Number' format.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But, I tried it and still get such weird values.

Comment: Which Excel version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls)

Comment: I'm not convinced there's a solution in those versions, aside from choosing the number format with a fixed number of decimal places. Without this Excel version to hand I can't verify.

Answer (score 1):

Testing in Excel 2003:

Number tested: `123456789098765000`
Cell format General: `1.23457E+17`
Cell format Number (0 decimal places): `123456789098765000`